# Bookmarks are associated with wrong page after some pages got deleted

Tags: c#, itext

I used iTextSharp open source library.

I tried both PdfWriter and PdfStamper:

For PdfStamper I have code below (toDelegePageNumbers will be ",!4,!5" after code execution):

```
stamper.Outlines = bookmarks; 
reader.SelectPages("1-" + reader.NumberOfPages + toDelegePageNumbers); 
stamper.Outlines = bookmarks; 
stamper.Close();
```

And alternatively for PdfWriter I used code below (w is PdfWriter):

```
foreach (int page in pageToKeep) 
{ 
    doc.NewPage(); 
    w.DirectContent.AddTemplate(w.GetImportedPage(reader, page), 0, 0); 
} 
w.Outlines = bookmarks; 
doc.Close();
```

In either scenario, bookmark originally point to Page 6 still point to Page 6 in the newly generated pdf file, which is wrong since page 4 and 5 have been deleted, original page 6 should be page 4 in the new document.

Is there any way we could preserve bookmarks without doing manual page number shifting? We have many existing bookmarks, and only need to delete two pages, it seems extra work for a simple operation.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In iText7(both Java and .Net), you can use PdfMerger to copy all but the pages you want to delete and bookmarks will be updated. I'll have to see if iText5 contains similar functionality.

Comment: @SamuelHuylebroeck thanks for the information, I searched there is no pdfMerger in iText5, it's only in iText7, unfortunately our company policy doesn't allow us to use iText7. we just manually updated the bookmarks.

Comment: You could try using PdfCopy or PdfSmartCopy in iText5, but I don't think it updates the bookmarks.

Comment: Yes I tried them as well.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to do it manually then. iText7 does it internally by keeping a page2page map, linking old page in the source document with the new page, and iterates over bookmarks at the end, updating the destination when copying them into the new document.